# How to see access token when using a sessionmanager?

Tags: ios, swift, session, spotify

I'm using the Spotify API, and followed the instructions for their iOS SDK setup. This involved abstracting away/delegating away most of the work to the SPTSession/SPTSessionManager. But now that everything is abstracted away, how can I get my access token so that I can do "manual" calls (using URL, URLSession, URLRequest, etc classes in Swift)?

The instructions for set up had me include a lazy var sessionmanager (an instance of SPTSessionManager) defined via closure that manages my SPTSession, and I know an SPTSession has members access_token and refresh_token. However, I can't seem to access them outside of my Appdelegate because sessionmanager is a lazy var in AppDelegate. I tried making global variables for the tokens outside of appdelegate, but I can't seem to find a way to actually set the values since sessionmanager is completely abstracted away. Even when I'm in the AppDelegate, if I try doing sessionmanager.session?.access_token it sends me into an infinite loop, which I assume is because sessionmanager is a lazy variable so every time I try to get it, the closure just reevaluates?

I'm not sure what's going on. Also, I'm not very familiar with stackoverflow etiquette so please let me know if there's anything I should do differently!

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, SPTSessionManagerDelegate {
    // Default appdelegate methods and other irrelevant code

    // implement session delegate
    func sessionManager(manager: SPTSessionManager, didInitiate session: SPTSession) {
        isLoggedIn = true
        authToken = session.accessToken
        refreshToken = session.refreshToken
        print("success", session)
    }

    func sessionManager(manager: SPTSessionManager, didFailWith error: Error) {
        print("fail", error)
    }

    func sessionManager(manager: SPTSessionManager, didRenew session: SPTSession) {
        authToken = session.accessToken
        print("renewed", session)
    }

    let SpotifyClientID = "b29fa2b4649e4bc697ecbf6721edaa39"

    let SpotifyRedirectURL = URL(string: "spotify-ios-quick-start://spotify-login-callback")!

    lazy var configuration = SPTConfiguration(
      clientID: SpotifyClientID,
      redirectURL: SpotifyRedirectURL
    )

    // Setup token swap via glitch
    lazy var sessionManager: SPTSessionManager = {

        if let tokenSwapURL = URL(string: "https://spotify-token-swap.glitch.me/api/token"),
        let tokenRefreshURL = URL(string: "https://spotify-token-swap.glitch.me/api/refresh_token") {
        self.configuration.tokenSwapURL = tokenSwapURL
        self.configuration.tokenRefreshURL = tokenRefreshURL
        self.configuration.playURI = ""
      }
      let manager = SPTSessionManager(configuration: self.configuration, delegate: self)
      return manager
    }()

    // Request to login with Spotify. Called from a different file.
    func requestSpotify() {
        let requestedScopes: SPTScope = [.userTopRead, .playlistModifyPublic]
        sessionManager.initiateSession(with: requestedScopes, options: .default)
    }

    // Configure auth callback
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
      self.sessionManager.application(app, open: url, options: options)
      return true
    }
}
```

Edit: As a separate issue, I can't seem to actually open the login flow cause I have an "invalid client", even though I've whitelisted my redirect uri and I'm sure my client id is correct?

Comment: Hi Allyson it would really help if you could share the relevant code. Show us how you defined your and accessed your properties.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the tip! I just added the relevant code.